# What does “It's gonna be sick” mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

From Ordinary World 2016:

> Hey, today's my birthday, man.
>
> Um, and I'm thinking about having a party,like a daytime blowout kinda
>   party.
>
> So... Yeah, dude, um, as soon as you get this, or...
>
> I'll call you back. As soon as I get a location, I'll call you back.
>
> It's gonna be sick.

Is "It's gonna be sick." an idiom? or is it a common expression?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's an idiom, but with a wide variety of meanings.  It could be taken fairly literally to mean that the party will be very bad, or it could be much the opposite, with "sick" being used in the reverse sense to mean "great".  Many words -- "cool", "bitchin'", etc -- are used by youth and those in the counter-culture in the opposite sense, and some make it into the wider colloquial English.

Comment: I would note that within certain groups the term could have sexual implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "excellent" or "very impressive". In this context, "sick" is an example of an **inverted meaning.** From the [Oxford Dictionaries blog:](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/05/inverted-meanings-sick/)

> A common trick of slang is to invert meanings, so that seemingly negative words are used as terms of approval. *Bad* and *wicked* are two established examples, although it may surprise you to see just how far back their positive uses go....
>
> *Sick* is a more recent arrival, first seen as a US synonym for ‘excellent’ or ‘very impressive’ in 1983:
>
> …it was a sick party and there were tons of cool people there.

Comment: interesting ! 1++